# Android ActionBar Sherlock Swipe Gesture Recogniser

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I have an application that has action bar sherlock and [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) integrated in it, the application has only 3 pages, and they're static pages, so no big deal about them. I have one activity and 3 fragments that i am changing when using the sliding menu.

What i want to achieve is something like this image [image]

I want the user to be able to swipe with his finger on the ActionBar, and when that happens i change the fragment that is being displayed.

Note: i got the gesture recogniser from this awesome [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures), but i can't seem to find a way to attach it to the ActionBar.

If i could put a View on the action bar and detect swipe on it, that would be great, but how can i do that ?!?

One last thing, how to implement this "Page Control" in android ?!?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my question is that i simply created a `custom_actionbar.xml`, and then i used this to do the following:

```
View custom = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);
getActionBar().setCustomView(custom);
// and you can use the things in the custom action bar like following !!
Button btnLeft = (Button) custom.findViewById(R.id.btnMenu);
```

Hope it helps someone :)